# How can I order objects by months from a JSON array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

this is my JSON array

```
"_embedded": {
"incidents": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Golpe",
        "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
        "timestamp": "2015-01-01T00:00:00-0700",
        "upload_date": "-0001-11-30T00:00:00-0700",
        "archived": false,
        "_links": {
            "self": {
                "href": "http://incidents-core/app_dev.php/incidents/1"
            },
            "attachments": {
                "href": "http://incidents-core/app_dev.php/incidents/1/attachments"
            },
            "comments": {
                "href": "http://incidents-core/app_dev.php/incidents/1/comments"
            },
            "thumbnail": {
                "href": "http://incidents-core/app_dev.php/attachments/33/download"
            }
        },
        "_embedded": {
            "device": "Samsung 300",
            "employee": "Juan Lopez",
            "incident_type": "Golpe",
            "profile": "PruebaUpdate",
            "attachmentsCount": 7,
            "commentsCount": 15
        }
    },
```

in the JSON I got many incidents with different dates, I would like to show in my index all the incidents like..total incidents in January , total incidents in February etc.. but I don't know how to start.
I'm using AngularJS to show the information from the JSON

```
 <div class="row">
            <h1>January</h1>
            <h3>Profile: ProfileName</h3>
            <div class="line-separator"></div>
            <div id="menu_options">
                <form class="form-inline">
                    <div class="btns-view">
                        Change View:
                        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                            <button ng-click="showme=true" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>
                            </button>
                            <button ng-click="showme=false" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <ul class="list" ng-hide="showme">
                <li class="list__item" ng-repeat="incident in incidents">
                    <!-- ngrepeat: mostrar total de incidentes-->
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#incidentModal" ng-click="selectIncident($index)">
                        <!-- /.badgetSection-->
                        <figure class="list__item__inner">
                            <div class="bagdets">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-comment"><span> {{incident._embedded.commentsCount}} </span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-picture"><span> {{incident._embedded.attachmentsCount}} </span>
                            </div>
                            <!-- ./badges -->
                            <div class="incident-image">
                                <img ng-src="{{incident._links.thumbnail.href || 'img/03.jpg'}}">
                                <p class="incident-type"><span>{{incident._embedded.incident_type}}</span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <figcaption>
                                <p>{{incident.name}}</p>
                                <div class="line-separator"></div>
                                <p>{{incident.description | strLimit: 90 }}</p>
                                <div class="line-separator"></div>
                                <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> {{incident.timestamp | date:'EEE - dd/mm/yyyy'}} <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> {{incident.timestamp | date:'hh:mm:ss a'}}</p>
                                <div class="line-separator"></div>
                                <p> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> {{incident._embedded.employee}}</p>
                            </figcaption>
                        </figure>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- /.list -->
```

Comment: You start by searching -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the date for epoch, and sort it. This uses `.sort()`:

```
function parseDate (a) {
    return Date.parse(a.match(/^(\d+\-\d+\-\d+)/)[1]);
}
```

Use this function as:

```
var json = 'YOUR_JSON_HERE';
json.incidents.sort(function(a,b){
    if (parseDate(a.timestamp) < parseDate(b.timestamp)) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (parseDate(a.timestamp) > parseDate(b.timestamp)) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

---

Because you are using AngularJS take a look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy). The `parseDate()`returns an [epoch](http://www.unixtimestamp.com) of the day/month. So the higher the number returned by `parseDate`, the "newer". The function takes in a string in the format of `timestamp`:

```
2015-01-01T00:00:00-0700
```